# How to store a function in a class variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a class for manipulating a list view functionality on a web page. But I have problem to finding a solution for `ListViewSelectedIndexChange` (you know what it is for). Actually I am not able to store a function for calling later.

Here is my code.

```
ListView = function (listViewID) {
    //unique listview id
    this.ID = listViewID;

    //event hanadler
    var SelectedIndexChanged: function = {};
    this.onSelectedIndexChanged = function (fn) { this.SelectedIndexChanged = fn;};
    //adds an item to listview
    this.addItem = function (items, itemTag) {
        var listViewTable = $("#" + this.ID + " table")[0];
        var itemsCount = items.length;
        var itemID = this.ID + "_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
        var trString = "<tr id=\"" + itemID + "\">";
        for (i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
            trString += "<td>" + items[i] + "</td>";
        }
        trString += "<td class=\"tag\"";
        trString += "</tr>";
        var newRow = $(trString);
        (function (eventHandler) {
            $(newRow).bind("click", function () { eventHandler(); });
        })(this.SelectedIndexChanged);

        $(listViewTable).append(newRow);
    }

    //returns number of items in the listview
    this.itemsCount = function () {
        var listViewTable = $("#" + this.ID + " table")[0];
        return $(listViewTable).find("tr").length - 1;
    }
    //removes the listview from DOM
    this.remove = function () {
        $("#" + this.ID).remove();
    }
}
```

And I use it this way.

```
var listView = new ListView(listViewID);
listView.addItem(["1", "2", "3"], "3");
listView.onSelectedIndexChanged = function () { alert("event fired"); };
```

But it doesn't work. Because only the
 original empty function will be executed.

Comment: this.SelectedIndexChanged = function {} ();

Answer (score 0):

Change `var SelectedIndexChanged: function = {};` to `var SelectedIndexChanged: function() {};`.

Comment: I also tried this.SelectedIndexChanged = function(){};. It doesn't work too.